# Joomla front page article should not be shown

Tags: joomla, frontpage, joomla-article

I have a weird problem.

Some articles are published on front page, some not.

1. When I check Article Manager, some articles are set to publish on front page which suppose to be not published on front page.
2. I correct values to unpublished.
3. Check front page which looks ok - right. Database also looks ok.
4. After some time i check front page and article are wrong, even in database are wrong.

Only I have access to Admin panel and database

Any doubt what should be wrong

I use 1.5.23

Answer (score 0):

Hi it sounds like your database could be corrupted. If you have access to phpadmin or equivalent, you could try a repair database command.

The next step would be to delete the db and create a new one, along with a new joomla installation

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the normal behaviour of [several of the extensions for Joomla!](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display) that change the contents of the front page, eg. [Auto-Frontpage](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/10986).

Before you take radical steps check that you don't have a Joomla extension that causes the front page to be updated automatically.

Comment: I check extensions and I can't find anything. I solved that I put only one category showed on front page

Answer (score -1):

and upgrade to 1.5.25 version and get ready for 2.5 version.

The 1.5 will be unsupported soon: April 2012!